# "The bond between children and their parents is the strongest bind on earth"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, nouns, sentence

Does this sentence make sense?

> The bond between children and their parents is the strongest bind on earth.

I'm having second thoughts on the right usage of *bind* and *bond.* It's also the hook of an essay I'm writing. Not sure if it's any good.

Comment: Can you give us some context and explain why you think this might or might not make sense?

Comment: I'm having second thoughts on the right usage of bind and bond. It's also the hook of an essay I'm writing.. Not sure if it's any good.

Comment: You don't really need the word *bind*; it could even be incorrect there. In any case, it's a question of proof-reading/ writing help which is off-topic on ELU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is neither good rhetorically nor what you mean grammatically.

Rhetorically, you want to repeat the word: *This X is the superlative X in the world.*

Grammatically, *bind* and *bond* are completely separate nouns.  You may be confused because *bind* as a verb can in some cases lead to creating a *bond* as a noun, but a (noun) *bind* is not at all a *bond*.

Although it is cliché, you would still be much better off with *The bond between children and their parents is the strongest bond on earth.*

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that bond ought to become bonds, and, as Old Pro has already explained, the use of the word "bind" is incorrect.

"The bonds between children and their parents are the strongest bonds on earth" or perhaps simply "The bonds between children and their parents are the strongest on earth," which eliminates the redundancy of the word "bond."